# JinjaSQL dynamic templates

Tags: python, sql, jinja2

I am using JinjaSQL to create dynamic SQL queries for filtering on a database. I want the filters to be modular, such that creating new filters are easy.

I want to insert the filters by inserting an appropriate template into a template. For example:

```
template = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE {{ filter | sqlsafe }}'
filter = 'date > {{ date_from }}'
data = {'filter': filter, 'date_from': 20200101}

query, params = prepare_query(template, data)
```

What I want is:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > %s'
params = [20200101]
```

What I get is:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > {{ date_from }}'
params = []
```

I guess I could fix this by simply running `prepare_query` again, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You cannot end with `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > {{ date_from }}` when your filter variable is `filter = '> {{ date_from }}'`. Please review your [mcve]

Comment: Simple typo. It's fixed now.